# How to make RSense autocomplete and jump to definitions of a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, emacs, autocomplete

I switched from netbeans to emacs and I am pretty happy with the change. The thing I am missing the most is autocompletion and jump to definitions. In order to get this I have installed Rsense. It works fine for the gems code, though, I cannot jump-to-definitions of my Rails project nor autocomplete according to the methods I defined.

I tried to add my project's load path to Rsense's load_path configuration, though, it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Is `auto-complete-mode` installed? (It's required for RSense completion.) Are the commands `ac-complete-rsense` and `rsense-jump-to-definition` available in Emacs (e.g. with `M-x`)?

Comment: Yes. I use rsense with autocomplete. But still, I am unable to jump to my own definitions by using Rsense. Rtags has been providing that functionality as stated on my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tags for browsing through files and jumping directly to function definitions.
I use Exuberant Ctags (its got Ruby support). You can download it from [here](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

I am assuming that you are working on windows. Getting the tags to work initially on windows is a pain especially if you are using emacs for the first time.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Install Cygwin from [here](http://www.cygwin.com/).
2. Include the cygwin\bin\ folder in your environment variable `PATH`. E.g. [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
3. Install exhuberant ctags. Note that emacs may sometime have a built in ctags. Later on you will have to use the `ctags` command in cygwin to create tags. At that time you may encounter some errors in case it uses the ctags in emacs instead of exuberant ctag.
4. Once you have installed ctags, add that to the environmental variable `PATH` as well.
5. If you have a small project with relatively lesser number of files (<500). So you just need a single global TAGS file. For that open cygwin, change your directory to the root directory of your project and type in the command `ctags -R -e` [Check this out](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#15) for other approaches
6. Your tags file will be created. It will be named "TAGS" and will be present in the root directory of your project.
7. Next open emacs, and browse through the code. In case you come across a function and want to jump to its definition, put your cursor on the function name and press `M-.` your minibuffer should then show something like `Find tag (default <function-name>):` Press Enter and voila!!! you are magically transported to the function definition!!!
   Note: You may have to specify the TAGS file the first time you use the `M-.` This needs to be done only once after emacs startup. You can also modify your .emacs file to take in the TAGS file automatically on startup.

Refer to [this](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Find-Tag.html#Find-Tag) and [this](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Tags-Search.html#Tags-Search) for more info for tags related commands in emacs.

Comment: does Ctags support Ruby? I have been using Rtags instead: http://simple-and-basic.com/2008/10/using-rtags-ang-gtags-for-coding-ruby.html

Comment: This is nice but unfortunately it doesn't address autocompletion

Comment: Did you try the default auto completion in emacs? `M-/`?

Answer (score 1):

Until now, I have been using rtags to jump to definitions. It's not perfect, but it does the trick in many cases.