# How can I jump into a function definition like I did in Visual Studio using F12?

Tags: emacs

I've been using Emacs for just 1 month... Jumping into function is always bugging me. My ecb configuration is shown below.

```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/site-lisp/ecb-2.40/")
   (require 'ecb)
   (global-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For current versions of emacs/cedet and C/c++ projects you don't need to bother with etags/ctags/global, as semantic takes care of analyzing your project -- it will use the tools present if need be.

If cedet is set up correctly, I guess the function(s) you want to try are `semantic-ia-fast-jump` and `semantic-complete-jump`.

That said, I suggest to work through Alex Otts  "gentle introduction to CEDET" [1](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html), setting up your project and configuring emacs as you progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can `etags` to generate a TAGS file for your project and use <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to jump to the desired function.

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd>`find -type f -name \*.[ch] -exec etags -a {\} \;`<kbd>RET</kbd>

I do this in the root directory for small projects, but if you want something more sophisticated you probably need to configure [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think you are right.. I am about to dig into CEDET a bit more ..thanks for your answer.~

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in a related topic which you can [find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669190/how-to-make-rsense-autocomplete-and-jump-to-definitions-of-a-rails-project/8473403#8473403) which uses exuberant ctags

Comment: Oh is it? Haven't tried GNU Global yet. Btb I chose exuberant ctags for its support for verilog. Unfortunately I don't see GNU Global having any support for verilog. Do you know of any other options which I can try out?